# Docker - List environment variables defined in dockerfile from within a container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

Is there a way to list all the environment variables defined in *dockerfile* (or *docker-compose.yml*) from within a container but **only** the ones defined in *dockerfile*, without variables like `PATH`, `PS1`, `TERM`,... ??

My container is the [*php-apache-dev*](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/tree/master/docker/php-apache-dev/ubuntu-18.04) container from *webdevops* which is based on the ubuntu image.

Comment: There's no way to tell where an environment variables come from within a container. If you have access to the Docker socket, you can `docker inspect` the container to get a list of Docker-defined environment variables, but you would not normally expose the Docker socket into your containers.

Comment: There is a hack to it, Use [undocker](https://github.com/larsks/undocker/) to extract the **Dockerfile** and read ENV from there.

Answer (score 2):

You should not assign root privileged just for the sake of ENV, better to print all env and exclude the system environment that you are not intrested in.

The best option is to grep only that are defined in Dockerfile is to print all env that start from `WEB_`, as your mentioned Dockerfile ENV all start from `WEB_*`.

```
ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app \
    WEB_DOCUMENT_INDEX=index.php \
    WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=*.vm \
    WEB_PHP_TIMEOUT=600 \
    WEB_PHP_SOCKET=""
ENV WEB_PHP_SOCKET=127.0.0.1:9000
ENV WEB_NO_CACHE_PATTERN="\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|svg|json|xml)$"
```

So this will print Dockerfile ENV only.

```
docker run -it --rm webdevops/php-apache-dev printenv | grep -E "^WEB"
```

Or to exclude some variables you can try

```
docker run -it --rm webdevops/php-apache-dev printenv | grep -vE "^PATH|^HOME|^TERM"
```

this will not show your mentioned ENV that you are not intrested in.